# Maxmind JavaScript API doesn't support TLD-less (local) domains

Tags: javascript, zombie.js, maxmind

I'm using the JavaScript API (http://dev.maxmind.com/geoip/geoip2/javascript/) which works well. However using zombie.js (zombie.labnotes.org) for testing my UI I'm seeing errors:

> Error: Server returned status code 401 from https://geoip-ipv4.maxmind.com/geoip/v2.1/city/me

Presumably this is because there's no referrer and the page is rendered from a localhost:port URL. The Maxmind UI doesn't allow me to add TLD-less domains (e.g. localhost).

If I attempt to mock the request:

```
browser.resources.mock('https://geoip-ipv4.maxmind.com/geoip/v2.1/city/me', {});
```

I get:

> Error: undefined: Cannot make request to different domain

I this a bug with Maxmind's API or zombie?

Comment: The MaxMind JS service does work with a referrer of "localhost", but it won't work without any referrer at all, which I assume is what is being sent.

Answer (score 0):

According to the error code 401 as published in the web site, there are 2 possibilities of getting this error.

Reason 1:
The domain of your site is not registered.

Reason 2:
You tried to access a service or feature that is not covered by your service plan.